# ASP.NET Core DLLs references

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dll, reference

I am using two web sites using common dll.

```
C:/Website1 bin  
C:/Website2 bin
C:/Library/Project1 bin
```

On the development environment I have references from both web sites to the "`Library/Project1 bin`"

I am using `ASP.NET .NET Core 3.0.`

Do I need to use the same folder structure on the hosting server to keep references working?

Answer (score 1):

You can add all 3 projects into one solution and reference the project instead the DLL from the bin folder. Like this in the compilation the dll will be automatically generated and copied.

If you need to keep a reference to an external DLL you need to select copy if newer option in the dll properties.

[image]

Home this help :)